# Functional reasoning

Tags: agda

Some imports and definitions first.

```
open import Level hiding (suc)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Algebra
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open CommutativeSemiring commutativeSemiring hiding (_+_; _*_; sym)

data Even : ℕ -> Set where
  ezero : Even 0
  esuc  : {n : ℕ} -> Even n -> Even (suc (suc n))

_^2 : ℕ -> ℕ
n ^2 = n * n

unEsuc : {n : ℕ} -> Even (suc (suc n)) -> Even n
unEsuc (esuc e) = e

remove-*2 : (n : ℕ) -> {m : ℕ} -> Even (n + n + m) -> Even m
remove-*2  0          e = e
remove-*2 (suc n) {m} e
    with subst (λ n' -> Even (suc (n' + m))) (+-comm n (suc n)) e
... | esuc e1 = remove-*2 n e1
```

Now I want to prove `{n : ℕ} -> Even (n ^2) -> Even n` in a nice way, similar to ≡-Reasoning. I've finished with

```
infix 4 ∈_

data ∈Wrap {α : Level} {A : Set α} : A -> Set α where
  ∈_ : (x : A) -> ∈Wrap x

infix 3 #⟨_⟩_
infixl 2 _$⟨_⟩'_ _$⟨_⟩_

#⟨_⟩_ : {α : Level} {A : Set α} -> A -> ∈Wrap A -> A
#⟨ x ⟩ _ = x

_$⟨_⟩'_ : {α β : Level} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β}
        -> (x : A) -> (f : (x : A) -> B x) -> ∈Wrap (B x) -> B x
x $⟨ f ⟩' _ = f x

_$⟨_⟩_ : {α β : Level} {A : Set α} {B : Set β}
       -> A -> (A -> B) -> ∈Wrap B -> B
_$⟨_⟩_ = _$⟨_⟩'_

even-sqrt : {n : ℕ} -> Even (n ^2) -> Even n
even-sqrt {0}            ezero   = ezero
even-sqrt {1}            ()
even-sqrt {suc (suc n)} (esuc e) =
    #⟨ e ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + suc (suc (n + n * suc (suc n))))
    $⟨ subst Even (+-comm n (suc (suc (n + n * suc (suc n))))) ⟩ ∈
  Even (suc (suc (n + n * suc (suc n) + n)))
    $⟨ unEsuc ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + n * suc (suc n) + n)
    $⟨ subst (λ n' -> Even (n' + n)) (+-comm n (n * suc (suc n))) ⟩ ∈
  Even (n * suc (suc n) + n + n)
    $⟨ subst (λ n' -> Even (n' + n + n)) (*-comm n (suc (suc n))) ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + (n + n * n) + n + n)
    $⟨ subst (λ n' -> Even (n' + n + n)) (sym (+-assoc n n (n * n))) ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + n + n * n + n + n)
    $⟨ subst Even (+-assoc (n + n + n * n) n n) ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + n + n * n + (n + n))
    $⟨ subst Even (+-assoc (n + n) (n * n) (n + n)) ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + n + (n * n + (n + n)))
    $⟨ remove-*2 n ⟩ ∈
  Even (n * n + (n + n))
    $⟨ subst Even (+-comm (n * n) (n + n)) ⟩ ∈
  Even (n + n + n * n)
    $⟨ remove-*2 n ⟩ ∈
  Even (n * n)
    $⟨ even-sqrt ⟩ ∈
  Even n
    $⟨ esuc ⟩ ∈
  Even (suc (suc n))
```

Is there any standard reasoning for such purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anything inside Agda's standard library, but it provides almost what you need in the `Function` module. You can do without `∈Wrap`. Let me propose a little syntactic sugar:

```
infix 4 _⟧
infixr 3 _─_⟶_
infix 2 _⟦_

_⟧ : ∀ {α} → (A : Set α) → A → A
_⟧ _ = id

_⟦_ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} → (a : A) → {B : A → Set β} → ((x : A) → B x) → B a
a ⟦ f = f a

_─_⟶_ : ∀ {α β γ} (A : Set α) → {B : A → Set β} → (f : (a : A) → B a) →
        {C : {a : A} → (b : B a) → Set γ} → (∀ {a} → (b : B a) → C b) →
        (a : A) → C (f a)
A ─ f ⟶ g = g ∘ f
```

Then you can write your proof as:

```
...
even-sqrt {suc (suc n)} (esuc e) = e ⟦
  Even (n + suc (suc (n + n * suc (suc n))))
    ─ subst Even (+-comm n (suc (suc (n + n * suc (suc n))))) ⟶
...
    ─ remove-*2 n ⟶
  Even (n * n)
    ─ even-sqrt2 {n} ⟶
  Even n
    ─ esuc ⟶
  Even (suc (suc n)) ⟧
```

The main benefits of this variant are:

- There is no wrapper type. You are just working with functions.
- The nesting is done the right way. With the approach presented in the question, you cannot refine a hole at the end with `_$⟨_⟩_`, so you always end up editing code outside the last hole.

It would be nice to have this functionality in the standard library and the way to do that currently is to open an issue or pull request on [github](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/). Can you do that?

Comment: I don't have github account. If no one opens an issue in a three days, I'll open it.
Why not
_⟦_⟧ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} → (a : A) → {B : A → Set β} → ((x : A) → B x) → B a
a ⟦ f ⟧ = f a

Comment: You cannot merge those functions due to bracing. Let me add explicit braces to a small example: `x ⟦ ( t1 ─ f1 ⟶ (t2 ⟧))`. This is due to the use of `infixr` rather than `infixl` and is what makes working with holes easier. `PreorderReasoning` has the very same `infixr`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, explanations and opening the issue. I think it's worth adding less dependent variant of `_─_⟶_` and renaming `_─_⟶_` to `_─_⟶'_`, since dependent combinators produce unresolved metas, when applied to non-dependent functions, and latter appear more often.

Comment: In my experience those metas get solved when the definition is complete. Even though "everything is yellow" as long as there are open holes, it still enables you to work with holes sensibly and in the end all metas are resolved.